# How to implement playlist concept in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, playlist

In my Ruby on Rails project I have a **User** model and a **Content** model.

A User `has_many :contents` and a Content `belongs_to :user`.

Now, I want to create the idea of playlist. There will be more than one playlists, and each one will have some contents in some order. At this moment, it doesn't matter if a user owns a playlist or not, they'll be general.

**A playlist doesn't have any kind of association with a User. They will be general, owned by the system.**

I think the solution will be something like having a model **Playlist** and another table with these attributes: `playlist_id:integer content_id:integer order:integer`. But do I really need to create all the MVC parts to this new relationship?

As I looked into Rails associations, I got confused and I don't know how to do this, if using the *through* property, using `has_and_belongs_to_many` in both **Content** and **Playlist** or even how to create this new relationship.

I'd be glad if someone could help me, as you can see, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Do you intend for a User to only access their Content through a Playlist?  If so, `through` is probably what you want, but if a User should be able to access Content that isn't in a Playlist, `through` could be limiting.

Comment: A user is able to access all contents. The playlist's only goal is to have some ordered contents that will be passed as JSON to a JavaScript file in another machine. They aren't created to limit users access.

Comment: So if we were diagram this, what you want is a) Users <-> Content; b) Users <-> Playlist; and (c) Playlist <-> Content, right?  (where, "<->" means some kind of association)

Comment: One more thing, if the User is to access a Playlist, will that Playlist ever have content the user doesn't already own?

Comment: A user has no kind of association with a playlist. This playlist concept is just about contents and playlists. A playlist can have many contents and a content may belong to more than one playlist. A content may exist without belonging to any playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for you is use has_many through

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ... user code in here with no association
end

class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :content_playlists
  has_many :contents, through: :content_playlists
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :content_playlists
  has_many :playlists, through: :content_playlists
end

class ContentPlaylist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content
  belongs_to :playlist
end
```

The migration:

```
class CreateAll < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contents do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :playlists do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :content_playlists do |t|
      t.belongs_to :content
      t.belongs_to :playlist
      t.integer :order
      t.timestamps
    end

   add_index(:content_playlists, :content_id)
   add_index(:content_playlists, :playlist_id)       

  end
end
```

Now, you can assign a order integer on *content_playlists*, and in the future you can reorder your playlist changing the value on *contents_playlists*.

To add a new content_playlist:

```
c = Content.create(name: "Song 2")
p = Playlist.create(name: "My Playlists2)
ContentPlaylist.create(content: c, playlist: p, order: 1)
```

Reference: 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

You can see (fork, clone, do whatever you want) here:
https://github.com/bdfantini/hmt_example

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I really need. Playlists in my application don't belong to a user, they're general and eventually made by a admin or something... So, by now, I don't want them to have any association with users and because of that, this answer isn't exactly what I need.

Comment: Reading what you want i'll create another answer for you

Comment: But doing it like that, how could I have more than one Playlist and keep the contents in some arbitrary order? My goal is to have a main playlist (eventually more than one) whose contents order can be changed. I'm not sure I can do that with just "has_many :contents".

Comment: You can't with `has_and_belongs_to_many`, you'll need a `has_many through:`, where the joining table has attributes for `order/priority`. A `PlaylistItem` might work here.

Comment: Don't forget indexes for the tables.

Comment: Edited, now the association is only between contents and playlists, with and order relation.

Comment: Damien Roche, indexes aren't completely necessary in this case, I don't think you want to access directly to *contents_playlists*, is just an association model.

Comment: You most definitely *do* want indexes on join columns. Where did you hear they aren't necessary because you're not referencing the table directly?

Comment: If you can add an index to the answer, I'll +1 and delete mine. This is actually what the asker is looking for.

Comment: Also, see here for more info on indexes: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/soliddb/v6r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.soliddb.sql.doc/doc/choosing.columns.to.index.html

Comment: For those `add_index(:contents_playlists, :content_id)` and `add_index(:contents_playlists, :playlist_id)` to work, do I need to explicitly create the content_id on the table create? Not doing that I'm having an error message, saying that field doesn't exist. Not sure if this way is correct.

Comment: And how do I add a content to a playlist using this new table, now? I'm sorry if I'm asking newbie questions, but that's what I really am. So if you could give me a little extra help.

Comment: @gd.silva any luck yet? Sure, try `t.integer :content_id` and `t.integer :playlist_id`, but it could be that `t.belongs_to :contents/playlists` shouldn't be plural. It should be `t.belongs_to :content/playlist`.

Comment: @DamienRoche, the plural was the problem. Now I have all those models and migrations like above, but I'm not sure about how to create a ContentPlaylist. What should my form be like? And the controller? I created ContentPlaylist with a `rails g scaffold ContentPlaylist`, without any attributes and then I changed the migration to be like the above.

Comment: @gd.silva hi. I'm not too sure. Might be worth pinging the answer author and having him update his answer.

Comment: @Fantini I'll accept your answer if you help me a bit more with what's missing.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I've been with lots of works, please be patient, I can help you tomorrow, i'll create and upload an example to github, so you (and others) can use it.

Comment: @Fantini, I've tried this but I'm having some problems when trying to create a new instance in `ContentsPlaylists`. I'm not sure about how to create the form and the controller, because they show `:id` missing errors. Could you help me?

Comment: @gd.silva I'm very sorry for taking too long to answer, I've updated with the correct solution, also I've added a github repo that you can clone or fork.

Comment: @Fantini, could you provide some views with the forms to help me? Like being able to add contents to a playlist when seeing the playlist "show" view. Thanks

Comment: Gd.silva You can try formtastic, they usually do all the work for you: https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing something like this is what you want:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :contents
  has_many :playlists
  has_many :playlisted_contents, :through => :playlists
  ...
end

class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :contents
  ...
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to  :user
  belongs_to  :playlist
  ...
end
```

I'd start there, and write some tests to see if it's behaving as you want.  If your design has other constraints, we might need to adjust this some.

Comment: I think it's near that but I don't want a User to have any kind of association with a Playlist. Playlists are general, they belong to the system itself. So, this is not really what I need.